# Filtering a noise of F[sig] frequency [Example 20Khz] in measurement system

Tags: filters, noise, sampling

I am developing a system where there is inherent noise of F[sig] frequency. This is a DC measurement system and want to get rid of the noise by sampling at F[samp] samples per rate and taking multiple number of samples.

I know that if F[samp] is a multiple of F[sig], then i can filter the noise.
If F[samp] / F[sig] is not an integer , how can i measure the noise reduction which will take F[samp], F[sig] and number of samples [N] into equation?

Sorry if this is a very basic question.

Comment: Hi. We'd appreciate some more context: what filter are you using in the integer multiple case? Is it a moving average? What filters have you tried, if any, for more general noise filtering? Is the noise a pure tone at Fsig, or is this the noise bandwidth?

Comment: Hi Juancho, We are not looking for any filter. I want to calculate how much noise reduction will be obtained by sampling enough number of points. So intend is to find ball park number for noise reduction using F[samp], F[sig] and N .